# Looping through folder and finding specific file in R

Tags: r, file, loops

I am trying to loop through many folders in a directory, looking for a particular xml file buried in one of the folders. I would then like to save the location of that file and then run my code against that file (I will not include that code in this). What I am asking here is to loop through all the folders and then open the specific file.
For example:
My main folder would be: C:\Parsing
It has two folders named "folder1" and "folder2".
each folder has an xml file that I am interested in, lets say its called "needed.xml" 
I would like to have a scrip that loops through the directory and finds those particular scripts. 
Do you know how I could that in R.

Answer (score 3):

Using `list.files` and `grepl`you could look recursively through all sub-folders

```
rootPath="C:\Parsing"
listFiles=list.files(rootPath,recursive=TRUE)
searchFileName="needed.xml"

presentFile=grepl(searchFileName,listFiles)


if(nchar(presentFile)) cat("File",searchFileName,"is present at", presentFile,"\n")
```

Comment: Thanks but what I was thinking that I wouldnt have to give it the folder 1 and folder 2 names. I might have like 30 folders in the directory so was thinking that I can automatically search through all the folders for the particular file.

Comment: edited so that the file search is recursive through the sub-folder, let us know if this works

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
require(XML)

fol <- list.files("C:/Parsing")

for (i in fol){
               dir <- paste("C:/Parsing" , i, "/needed.xml",  sep = "")

                 if(file.exists(dir) == T){
                                           needed <- xmlToList(dir) 
                                           }
              }
```

This will locate your xml file and read it into R as a list. I wasn't clear from your question if you wanted the output to be the data itself or just the directory location of your data which could then be supplied to another function/script. If you just want the location, remove the 'xmlToList' function.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this (replace *.xml with your filename.xml if you want):

```
list.files(path = "C:\Parsing", pattern = "*.xml", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
```

This will recursively look for files with extension `.xml` in the path `C:\Parsing` and return the `full path` of the matched files.